# Identifying the main clause and subordinate clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses, relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses, syntactic-analysis

I’m preparing for my exam and in one of the practice questions i have to identify the main clause, subordinate clause/s and the subject,predicate and/or adverbials. the sentence is:

"The Mausoleum has an interesting place in Greek history because it was a building that was not dedicated to the gods".

i thought the main clause could be "The Mausoleum has an interesting place in Greek history"

with "because" being the subordinating conjunction.

but I'm really struggling to identify the subordinate clause/s. is there 1 or 2? what type of clause is it and what would the subject and predicate be?

thanks in advanced

Comment: You've just changed the sentence! Originally, it was 'Today, people can still see some of the marble stones that were used to build the Mausoleum". Do you intend to change it again?

Comment: I have 2 sentences that I'm struggling to analyse. I thought i would post both. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Homework questions may be OT.

Comment: It’s for university. We don’t get marked on it I just want to understand what the subordinate clause is? My course is all online so I don’t really have anyone to ask for advice.

Comment: First find all the verbs and their subjects.

Comment: Ive done that. Subject ‘the mausoleum’. Predicate: ‘has an interesting place in Greek History’. But after that I’m confused on if there is 1 or 2 subordinate clauses. I know ‘Because’ is a subordinating conjunction, then ‘it’ would be the subject, and ‘was a building’ would be the predicate. But then I get confused with ‘that’. Because there is no subject after ‘that’, yet it is clearly adding more information. My exam is tomorrow and I really need a good mark to pass the course  I would appreciate any help or guidance

Comment: The sentence as a whole is the main clause where "the mausoleum" is subject and the remainder is the predicate. There are three embedded subordinate clauses, as bracketed here: “The Mausoleum has an interesting place in Greek history because [it was a building [that __ was [not dedicated to the gods]]]". The first sub clause is a declarative content clause functioning as complement to "because", where the subject is “it” and the predicate “was a building that was not dedicated to the gods”.

Comment: The second sub clause is a relative clause modifying “building”, where the subject is gap, i.e. ___, and the predicate “was not dedicated to the gods”. Finally, the third sub clause is “not dedicated to the gods”; it is subjectless, though the subject is understood as “building”, which has “not dedicated to the gods” as predicate. Note that strictly speaking "that" is not a relative pronoun but a subordinator, hence the subject of the relative clause being represented by the ___ notation, called 'gap'.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help Bill, i appreciate it so much

Answer (score 1):

There are two subordinate clauses in this complex sentence:
1. Because... - a causal clause. This is the clause of the first level of subordination.
2. That... - a defining relative clause. This is the  clause of the second level of subordination.

Comment: I thought this as well, but I got confused because there is no subject in the 2nd subordinating clause

Comment: It is 'that' which is the subject of the clause.

Comment: In modern grammar, "that" is not treated as a relative pronoun but as a subordinator, so it can't be the subject of the relative clause. Instead, the missing subject is represented by the '___' notation, called 'gap', as thus: "a building that ___ was not dedicated to the gods".